# post to my wall with a large image not a thumbnail, with FB.api javascript?

Tags: facebook

I have searched everywhere but I cant get an answer!

If I post a message from within facebook and also upload a big image at the same time, then in my timeline - startpage the image is displayed all across the hole width of the timeline.

Question: Can you upload a image with the javascript api so that the image is big in the timeline-wall?

I have tryed everything I have found with FB.api, FB.ui, with stream.publish, dialogs, status.set etc and ALL of them displays THUMBNAIL images in the post.

Does anybody know if its possible to post a message and that the post looks just like you have post it from within facebook(with a big image and not a thumbnail)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem but finally got it working! Just call the following js function by clicking a button or whatever:

```
function onClickPublish() {

    FB.api('me/photos', 'post', {
        message: 'Only use message and url so the pictures takes all the space',
        url: 'http://www.site.com/this/is/the/picture.jpg'
        }, function (r) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(r));
        });
    }
}
```

This should display a dialog either specifying the ID-or-whatchamacallit of the post, otherwise, it may fail for lack of permissions or whatever.